# Django: How to access URL regex parameters inside a middleware class?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, middleware, urlconf

I am working on a Django project on Google App Engine. I have a URL like:

`http://localhost:8080/[company]/projects/project`

Note that `[company]` is a URL parameter defined in my urls.py like:

`(r'(^[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]*)/projects/project/(\d*)', 'projects.views.project_form'),`

I want to get the value of `[company]` from a middleware where I will set the GAE datastore namespace to the `[company]` value.

Is it possible to get the `[company]` parameter from the request object passed in the `process_request` method of middleware class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using the `process_view` middleware, you will have access to the views arguments and therefore the company value. Have a look at the function's definition:

```
def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs)
    ...
```

> view_args is a list of positional arguments that will be passed to the view, and view_kwargs is a dictionary of keyword arguments that will be passed to the view.

so you should just be able to grab it from there, something like:

```
def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
    company = view_kwargs.get('company', None)
```

Here's some more info from the django book on how the named and unnamed groups in your urls translate to args and kwargs in your view:

http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter08/#cn38

particularly

> This [named url groups] accomplishes exactly the same thing as the previous example, with one subtle difference: the captured values are passed to view functions as keyword arguments rather than positional arguments.

Comment: It worked. I had to use view_args[0] to get the company name. Thanks a lot.